# Mutual information equality based on chain rule

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

I have an introduction to information theory course which states the following equality :

$I(X_1; Y_1; Y_2) = I(X_1; Y_1) + I(X_1; Y_2 | Y_1)$ ​

The professor claims this can be proved with the chain rule for mutual information.
But the application of the mutual information chain rule does not lead to this at all, using the formula :

$ I(X_1, ..., X_N ; Y) = \sum_{i} I(X_i ; Y | X_{i-1} , ..., X_1) $

Then it follows that,

$ I(Y_1 , Y_2 ; X_1) = I(Y_1 ; X_1) + I(Y_2 ; X_1 | Y_1) $

How can we prove the above equality ?

Answer (score 2):

In my class, I learned this as Kolmogorov's identity or the small chain rule. The proof is as follows,

$$\frac{P_{X_1Y_1Y_2}}{P_{X_1Y_1}P_{Y_2}}=\frac{P_{X_1Y_2}}{P_{X_1}P_{Y_2}}\cdot\frac{P_{Y_1|X_1,Y_2}}{P_{Y_1}P_{X_1}}$$

From here it should nicely follow that,

$$I(X_1;Y_1|Y_2)=I(X_1;Y_2)+I(X_1;Y_2|Y_1)$$